# Terraform resource group deployment in multiple subscriptions

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to use Terraform and Terragrunt to create a bunch of different resources in Azure.
Amongst others, I am deploying subscriptions and resource groups.

I have one central variable file that contains some metadata, and deploys resources based on that.
I can deploy all the subscriptions that I want, but I have an issue because I want to deploy resource groups within those subscriptions, and I am not sure how to do it the best way, since the resource group resource doesn't have a subscription parameter.

Variable file looks something like:

```
inputs = {

    departments = [
    {
        name = "test",
        region = "West Europe"
        email = "something@something.com"

    },
    {
        name = "test2"
        region = "West Europe"
        email = "someone@something.com"
    }
]
```

}

So in my resource group module I have defined it like this:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
for_each = {for dep in var.departments: dep.name => dep}

  name     = "rg-${each.value.name}"
  location = "${each.value.region}"
}
```

And that is ok, but I need to switch context to the correct subscriptions, so the resource groups are being placed in the proper subs.
Any ideas?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? Please let me know if you have any responses.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy resources in multiple subscriptions, you can use multiple providers, [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/providers/configuration.html#alias-multiple-provider-configurations) you can get more details and the example code below:

```
provider "azurerm" {
    subscription_id = "xxxxxx"
    tenant_id = "xxxxxx"
    client_id = "xxxxxx"
    client_secret = "xxxxxx"
}

provider "azurerm" {
    alias = sub2
    subscription_id = "xxxxxx"
    tenant_id = "xxxxxx"
    client_id = "xxxxxx"
    client_secret = "xxxxxx"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example1" {
    provider = azurerm
    ...
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example1" {
    provider = azurerm.sub2
    ...
}
```

And if you use the for_each in terraform, you can add the alias option in the input:

```
inputs = {

    departments = [
      {
        name = "test",
        provider = "azurerm"
        region = "West Europe"
        email = "something@something.com"

      },
      {
        name = "test2"
        provider = "azurerm.sub2"
        region = "West Europe"
        email = "someone@something.com"
      }
    ]
}
```

This is just an example, but it's the workaround. You can change the code as you need.

Comment: Ufortunately this won't work, as subscriptions are also created based on the input file. So it would create a sub called "{name}-sub" for instance. So i don't really have the posibility to define the providers the way you described.

Comment: @jonashoye It seems you only can use the local-exec to execute the Azure CLI command to create the resources in the new subscription. First, use the command `az account set --subscription subscription_id` to set the current subscription and then create the resources.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the code below can fix your problem. (it works for me!)

**main.tf**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_billing_mca_account_scope" "bl" {
  billing_account_name = var.billing_account
  billing_profile_name = var.billing_profile
  invoice_section_name = var.invoice_section
}

resource "azurerm_subscription" "subs" {
  subscription_name = "test-new"
  billing_scope_id  = data.azurerm_billing_mca_account_scope.bl.id
}

created Subscription
provider "azurerm" {
  alias           = "new_sub"
  subscription_id = azurerm_subscription.subs.subscription_id
  features {}
}

# Create a Resource Group in the newly created Subscription
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  provider = azurerm.new_sub
  name     = "new-rg-in-new-sub"
  location = "eastus2"
}
```

Note: if you face an error when creating the rg, then run again the `az login` and `terraform apply` again that will work, the az is not getting the new subscription automatically sometimes.